# How to scope a property to a custom directive in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, directive

is there a way to scope a property to a directive? Something like this so I can add foundation to it and clear it up (removing event listeners etc.) when the element is unbound?

```
Vue.directive('toggler', {
  inserted(el) {
    this.toggler = new Foundation.Toggler($(el)); 
  },
  unbind() {
    this.toggler.destroy();
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ok so this achieves what I wanted. Assigning the property to the element does the job.

```
Vue.directive('f-toggler', {
  inserted(el) {
    /* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
    el.fToggler = new Foundation.Toggler($(el));
  },
  unbind(el) {
    el.fToggler.destroy();
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `vnode.context` which will give you access to the data properties on the Vue instance:

```
Vue.directive('toggler', {
  inserted(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context.toggler = new Foundation.Toggler($(el)); 
  },
  unbind(el, binding, vnode) {
   vnode.context.toggler.destroy();
  },
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle to show the basic process: https://jsfiddle.net/dv5n39ta/

Comment: Thanks, but how would this work if I had multiple elements on one page that use this directive? As they would each be overwriting the toggler property right?

Comment: I would simply save the stuff on the element.

Comment: Could you give an example please? Would it clear up the event listeners if you're trying to destroy something assigned to a property on the element?

Comment: I'll let @LinusBorg answer, but I'm guessing he means something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/s3ogo3u8/